# annotation to attribute syntax: The annotation "@Security" in method App\Controller\… was never imported

Tags: symfony, attributes, symfony6, php-8.1

By switching my app from Sf5 to Sf6, I have annotation to attribute issues :

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Security" in method App\Controller\MyController::delete() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in {"path":"..\/..\/src\/Controller\/","namespace":"App\\Controller"} (which is being imported from "/var/www/config/routes/attributes.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "attribute" type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step was to move `config/routes.yaml` if you have it to `config/routes/attributes.yaml` and update the controller path (adding *../*) as mentionned at https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes

Second step was to convert security annotations to attributes. I used [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) to convert routes annotations to attributes but I didn't find rule to security, so to do something like :

```php
// annotation :
    /**
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
// --> attribute :
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]
```

I used vim (neovim) rexeg

```
%s/\(\s*\)\/\*\*\n\s*\* @Security("is_granted\(('ROLE_.*')\)")\n\s*\*\//\1#[IsGranted\2]/cg
```

and I removed use on FrameworkExtraBundle :

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
```

and removed deprecated FrameworkExtraBundle :
`composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle`

and the error was gone